# Trivia Crack Probability

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

In the game Trivia Crack, you answer a question with 4 possible answers. A "life line" you can use allows you to guess a second time if you were wrong the first time. What is the probability you will get the right answer, assuming you have no idea what the correct answer is?

I think it would be: 1/4+3/4*1/3=1/2

Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct . Another way to see it is that you get to choose two answers out of four.